# Why does Anaconda Navigator opens many "python.exe" proceses in Win7?

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-7

Since a week ago, every time I open Anaconda Navigator - v 2019.10 on Windows 7 (my current operating system) my computer becomes slow because multiple "python.exe" processes are opened where each one consumes between 5% to 25% of my CPU.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling even other versions like 2020.11 and 2019.03 but it does not work.
I have also noticed that the "Update Now" option no longer appears even though I have this old version.
What could I do to make Anaconda work properly?